# How do I receive a message in flutter when phone is connected to network?

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io

I'm building a chat application using [socket_io_client](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client) with flutter and node.js server. Everything works fine but my Question is, How do I receive all the messages when the phone is not connected to a network? Do I have to store these pending messages in the database like a queue and show them to the user when he is back online or is there any other strategy to do so with socket.io?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I solved it.

I have used [store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/store) package in my node.js. This will store all the users who are online and whenever a user posts any data from my flutter application, I will first check if the receiver is online and then I will emit the data if the user is online or I will store it in the server itself with receiver ID using the same store package. Now when the user is back online I will just check if the user's data list is empty, if not I will start emitting and deleting from the list until the list is empty.